# Add contact in WP7 without using show() method

Tags: windows-phone-7

I wish to add new contacts in WP7. I have used the following

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     SavePhoneNumberTask savePhoneNumber = new SavePhoneNumberTask();

     code.savePhoneNumber.Completed += new EventHandler<TaskEventArgs>(savePhoneNumber_Completed);

      savePhoneNumber.PhoneNumber = "1987654320";

      savePhoneNumber.Show();
}
```

This shows add more details of Contact page, if we press save then only it is saved.

But i want to save the contacts without calling Show() method.

Please anyone help me.....

Comment: This is not possible. You have tu use that launcher to add new contact, there is no other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't and you shouldn't be able to.

Imagine that we could add contacts silently. Apps would start spamming my contacts.

This is the way it works.